# Flutter hive: cannot generate Adapter files

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I have a model like so:

```
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'config_item.g.dart';

@HiveType()
class ConfigItem {
  @HiveField(0)
  String _id; // this can be a uuid or a MongoDB ObjectID
  @HiveField(1)
  final String deviceName;
....
}
```

I like to generate the Adapter file but it **does not want to do it**! When I call `flutter packages pub run build_runner build  --delete-conflicting-outputs` I get the following output:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build  --delete-conflicting-outputs                main  ✭ ✈
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 399ms

[SEVERE] Nothing can be built, yet a build was requested.
[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph...
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 45ms

[INFO] Checking for updates since last build...
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 399ms

[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] Running build completed, took 3ms

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 35ms

[INFO] Succeeded after 53ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)
```

In my `pubspec.yaml` I have:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  bottom_navy_bar: ^6.0.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  get_it_mixin: ^3.1.3
  servicestack: ^2.0.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.3
  uuid: ^3.0.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner:
```

I tried all sort of things like

- Delete .dart_tool folder
- Adding `*.g.dart` to `.gitignore`
- `flutter clean`
- and a lot more I found when searching the net.

**But nothing helps!** Any idea what is missing?

I am using the latest (stable) versions of flutter, dart SDK and AndroidStudio.

Comment: I think you are missing `hive_generator: ^1.1.1` in the dev dependencies.

Comment: That was the solution regarding the `build`. And I had to assign a typeId in the @HiveType annotation like so: `@HiveType(typeId : 1)`. Thanks a lot for the hint.

Answer (score 11):

Run this command :

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

But before that, you will have to import the generator.

Example : If your file name is project_database.dart, then in that file :

Import,

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
part 'project_database.g.dart'; //this will show an error initially but if
 // you run the above command, it will generate the generator file
```

Comment: That helped..=^

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue but I was missing `hive_generator: ^1.1.1`. I didn't find it in the original [Docs](https://docs.hivedb.de).

Special thanks to @Denny Mueller's comment

Answer (score 3):

```
pub run build_runner build
```

after got the part .save it and the error will gone

Also add hive_generator in ur dev_dependecies.

hive_generator package can automatically generate TypeAdapters for almost any class.

If you have any other problem
[refer here](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/generate_adapter)

Comment: adding ```hive_generator``` helped!

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --use-polling-watcher --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add hive_generator at the dev_dependencies. Here's the link
https://pub.dev/packages/hive_generator

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem. i solved by saving my changes in pubspec.yaml.
just press ctrl + s in pubspec.yaml then run flutter packages pub run build_runner build again.

Answer (score 0):

Give TypeId for @HiveType.

In your Case :

```
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'config_item.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class ConfigItem {
  @HiveField(0)
  String _id; // this can be a uuid or a MongoDB ObjectID
  @HiveField(1)
  final String deviceName;
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem

1-First you should stop the project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zukeO.png)

When the project is running ,You can't generate your file,
in this photo you should tap on red button to stop project

2- And now run this code in terminal (after add lib in dependencies)

```
dart run build_runner build
```

Answer (score 0):

I kinda had the same problem that the generator file wasn't written but please make sure that you've written the `part 'yourfile.dart'` part and then it creates the file automatically and writes the code.
in summary make sure you didn't make the generator file by yourself :)

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the following when typing `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` in my console.

```
Deprecated. Use `dart run` instead.
Could not find package "build_runner". Did you forget to add a dependency?
```

This command worked for me instead: `dart run build_runner build`